# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, port

It says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
```

Im using FastAPI in miniproject, and trying to run "database.py"

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/dbname"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

makes this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 645, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\database.py", line 10, in <module>
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5832, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3243, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3233, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3269, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2431, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 645, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Guest11\Desktop\fastapi_python\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found some information on internet, reinstalled postgreSQL, and also changed the
`"postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/dbname"`
from 5432 to 5433
`"postgresql://user:password@localhost:5433/dbname"`

(as it was said in other stackoverflow topic)
but if i change this port to any port except 5432 it gives a new error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

(just removing port from URL also doesnt work, it gives the same error as the first one)

im absolutely new to programming and i already spent really much time looking for solve.
help please

Comment: What does the _original error message_ say after `OperationalError`?

Comment: 1) Look at the Postgres log to see what is hitting the database. 2) I'm betting that one of the real values you aliased in `user:password@localhost:5432/dbname` is causing the issue. That it is some special character that is not being recognized properly.

Comment: yeah i openned logs and i realised that i need to create user and database to connect it my bad, now it works